# limit sql results via table selections

Tags: mysql

I am curious if it is possible to limit the results of an sql select statement by joining another table with selectable options. ie. Have one table that a user can use to update their preferences such as display a,c,d and do not display b and e. (assuming the table would only have columns a-e) (this has is separate from the question). Once the user has updated / selected their options im curious if i can create an sql select statement that would fetch the results of another table based off of the options selected by the user in the first table. I know can can create a larger statement that would include all of the results and omit them if the value is not provided. im curious if there is a way to only select particular columns based off of another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> im curious if there is a way to only select particular columns based
>   off of another table

No. Queries cannot have varying columns. Technically, you can make a stored procedure do something like that; but it is considered a rather poor practice.

...and doing it the right way is likely not going to be a "larger statement".